# Where is $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) set for builds in TFS2015?

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, build-agent

I'm trying to modify the value of this variable as it currently points to the source folder of whatever build gets run on the agent instead of the root of the build.

Does anyone know where I can modify this variable? I've looked at the agent's configuration .json file but didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in Variables tab in Build Definition.

I just had a quick test, if I define a new value to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, the output in the task for `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` will be the new value:

[image]

[image]