# The term 'System.DefaultWorkingDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to generate CSV file using powershell using VSTS release job and store it to current working directory. Strange thing is the same code is working fine previously. Only difference is previously i used inline scripting but now i am using file path.

```
$results = @()

$data = 
@{                       
    uname = $uname             
    upass = "Apple@123"
    uid = $uid    
}

$results += New-Object PSObject -Property $data 

$results | export-csv -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\1UserTestDocument.csv -NoTypeInformation 

write-host "Print all files in the current directory :"
Get-Item *
```

error :

```
2019-03-01T06:56:19.2333832Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'CmdletHasMember'.
2019-03-01T06:56:19.2515776Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Disconnect-AzureAndClearContext'.
2019-03-01T06:56:19.2515900Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Initialize-AzModule'.
2019-03-01T06:56:19.2515985Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Initialize-Azure'.
2019-03-01T06:56:19.2516046Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Initialize-AzureRMModule'.
2019-03-01T06:56:19.2516153Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Remove-EndpointSecrets'.
2019-03-01T06:56:19.2516240Z VERBOSE: Trying to disconnect from Azure and clear context at process scope
2019-03-01T06:56:19.2516312Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2019-03-01T06:56:19.7421197Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2019-03-01T06:56:20.2546250Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
2019-03-01T06:56:20.2796129Z ##[debug]Error record:
2019-03-01T06:56:20.2985848Z ##[debug]ForEach-Object : The term 'System.DefaultWorkingDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2019-03-01T06:56:20.3038684Z ##[debug]At D:\a\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\3.1.23\AzurePowerShell.ps1:125 char:9
2019-03-01T06:56:20.3044174Z ##[debug]+         ForEach-Object {
2019-03-01T06:56:20.3217983Z ##[debug]+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2019-03-01T06:56:20.3218533Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.DefaultWorkingDirectory:String) [ForEach-Object], CommandNotFoun    dException
2019-03-01T06:56:20.3218704Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

### [error]The term 'System.DefaultWorkingDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905758/where-is-system-defaultworkingdirectory-set-for-builds-in-tfs2015

Comment: No luck. same error message again. 2019-03-01T07:28:17.2933434Z ##[error]The term 'System_DefaultWorkingDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: is that call >> `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` particular to azure powershell? because it DOES NOT exist in standard powershell ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey its vsts token

Comment: @4c74356b41 - ah! thank you for the info! i was so confused ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you have to use `$env:variable_name_with_underscores_instead_of_dots` to retrieve it.

In your case its:

```
$env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory
```